# liquibase JAVA_OPTS was unexpected at this time

Tags: mysql, spring, maven, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I have installed liquibase and I am trying to use it. Every liquibase command returns with an error

- `JAVA_OPTS was unexpected at this time.`

I saw solutions to set JAVA_OPT environment variables but none of my colleagues have it even though their liquibase is working perfectly fine. I have same environment variables in system variables/path with them as:

- C:\Program Files\liquibase
- C:\Program Files\liquibase\jre\bin

I am using

- Liquibase v4.14.0
- MySQL v8.0.30
- Java SDK 8u333
- Apache-Maven 3.8.6

What causes this and how can I solve it?

UPDATE with more errors:

I reinstalled everything and configure them from scratch. Here is the errors I have. I am started to think the cause of the problem bigger than I think.[image: errors]

Comment: Could you please post the liquibase command you're trying to execute

Comment: "liquibase update" or only just "liquibase"

Comment: How's your JAVA_HOME variable set up? And how is it included in your PATH?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333" this is my JAVA_HOME. I have this path inside system variables/path too.

Comment: Such issues look like misconfigurations in JAVA_HOME/PATH variables. Perhaps there's some extra space or a typo. I suggest you double check it

Comment: I reainstalled everything and checked all environment variables and compare with someone who has no issue. Still have the error and have other errors on programs depend on environment variables like npm, maven. It is weird all of them have some issues.